# Seaborn Barplot not showing bars

Tags: pandas, seaborn, data-visualization

so I'm quite new two data science and I have been trying to plot a  bar graph for this dataset with seaborn but its not showing any bars along the y axis even though the sum of profits are significantly high.

```
#sum of profit by each region
 y = df.groupby('Region').Profit.sum()
 sns.barplot(x = df['Region'] , y = y)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQdbc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want a bar plot that shows the total profit per region. You do not need to use the `groupby` function for that. Seaborn will "summarize" the data for you.
Here's a demonstration using dummy data.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

regions_list = [r for r in "AAABBBBCCCCCDDDDDD"]
profit_list = np.random.rand(len(regions_list))
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Region":regions_list,
        "Profit":profit_list
    }
)
sns.barplot(data = df, x="Region",y="Profit",estimator=sum,ci=None)
```

[image: bar plot of totals]

Edit: `estimator` call added to `sns.barplot`.

Comment: @Sahil, great! please mark my response as the answer.